# E: Package 'openssh-client' has no installation candidate

Tags: ssh

How to install openssh cilent and server on ubundu 13.04. i tried sudo apt-get install openssh-client on 13.04, but i got this error. i could not install it.

```
mphil@mphil:~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-client
[sudo] password for mphil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openssh-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openssh-client' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH client is usually installed on ubuntu. No need to install it again. Secondly 13.04 is not supported anymore. Please upgrade to the latest LTS.

If you still want to install, see  [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) answer.

Comment: but i tried this command on terminal finally i got this error , how can i rectify this error. mphil@mphil:~$ ssh localhost
The program 'ssh' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install openssh-client

Comment: Fine, you have two options. 1) Upgrade to a supported distro. 2) See the link in my answer.

Comment: i'm new to ubundu and also linux. now i want to run hadoop on ubundu.  that's why i tried. thanks a lot.

Comment: Which ubundu version will suitable for hadoop ?

Comment: Go ahead and install 14.04.

Comment: where can i download 14.04 LTS  and is it free version?

Comment: Click [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=14.04.2&architecture=amd64).

Comment: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused, how to avoid in on ubundu 14.04 LTS for hadoop

Comment: @user3464055, DO you have `openssh-server` installed? Try `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. ALso next time, first search to see if a solution to the problem already exists. And if the solution does not exit, your are welcome to start a new question.

Comment: ya tried sir, but finally i got this error - drlawrance@drlawrance-Aspire-5742:~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @user3464055 You tried to ssh to localhost. Hence it can't be a firewall or router blocking it. Are you sure that openssh server installed? What is the output of `sudo service --status-all | grep ssh`?

Comment: i checked ssh on my machine using which ssh command and which sshd command, but i got the results /usr/bin/ssh . i could not get for sshd drlawrance@drlawrance-Aspire-5742:~$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh 
drlawrance@drlawrance-Aspire-5742:~$ which sshd

Comment: i got the out put for  this command,                            drlawrance@drlawrance-Aspire-5742:~$ sudo service --status-all | grep ssh
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot

Comment: can i try this  for that problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/546983/ssh-installation-errors

Comment: i solved the  above problems using this [http://askubuntu.com/questions/546983/ssh-installation-errors ]. thanks ..